# Referencing two data frames in a loop

Tags: r

I am hoping to write a loop that edits one data frame while accessing another in R. Lets say I have a data frame called 'master' set up as follows:

```
ID   type1   type2   type3
A    1       0       1
B    0       0       1
C    0       1       1
```

And a second data frame called 'reference' set up as follows:

```
Types   multiplier
type1   0.33
type2   0.44
type3   0.67
```

I would like to create a new column in 'master' that is the mathematical sum across rows multiplied by the 'multiplier' value in data frame 'reference'. For example, for ID 'A', this would be:

```
 master$newcolumn[A] <- (1 * 0.33) + (0 * 0.44) + (1 * 0.67)
```

My current attempt to do this is to convert the values in the second data frame to a list and run a loop on the first data frame, but I am having trouble. See below for my attempt. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
type_list <- as.list(reference$Types)

for i in type_list{
    master$newcolumn <- sum(master$i * reference$multiplier[reference$Types == i])
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this easily with `crossprod` by taking the input as the transpose of the 'master' after removing the 'ID' column with the second column ('multiplier') column of 'reference'

```
master$newcolumn <- crossprod(t(master[-1]), reference[,2])
master
#   ID type1 type2 type3 newcolumn
#1  A     1     0     1      1.00
#2  B     0     0     1      0.67
#3  C     0     1     1      1.11
```

Or use `%*%` operator

```
as.matrix(master[-1]) %*%  reference[,2]
```